# Prove that there exists no natural number $x$ such that $x^2-6$ is a perfect square

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof, square-numbers

I tried to prove this question using contradiction. I first assumed that there is such a perfect square and then claimed that any perfect square can be expressed in $n^2$, where $n$ is an integer, then I said that any perfect square is expressed as $(n-a)^2$, and factored $a^2-6$ using the quadratic formula and showed that $a$ can not be a natural number. This is a valid proof right?

Comment: Assuming for contradiction.  If $x^2 - 6 = k^2$ be a perfect square. Then $x^2 - k^2 = 6$. And so $(x-k)(x+k)=6$. Since $x,k$ are integers, $(x+k),(x-k)$ are also.  We can easily list out the optional factors that make six: $1\cdot 6, 2\cdot 3, 3\cdot 2, 6\cdot 1$.  Now figure out your $x,k$ from that.

Comment: Good idea but I can't tell whether you finished it correctly as you did not give your details. I would say if $n,m\in \Bbb N$ with $n^2-m^2=6$ then $(n+m)(n-m)=6$ with $n+m,n-m\in \Bbb N$ and $n+m>n-m,$ which implies $ [(n+m=6$ and $n-m=1)$ OR $(n+m=3$ and $n-m=2)],$ which implies $[(2n=(n+m)+(n-m)=7)$ OR $(2n=(n+m)+(n-m)=5)]$ which is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

A perfect square is always either $0 \bmod 4$ or $1 \bmod 4$.

Therefore either $x^2 - 6 \equiv 0-6 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ or $x^2-6 \equiv 1-6 \equiv 3 \bmod 4$, neither of which is possible for a perfect square.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$x^2-6=y^2 \Rightarrow x^2-y^2=6$$

Now use the difference of squares formula, and solve.

Note that if you look at the parities of $x-y, x+y$ you don't need to solve.